# Swift I can't manage to hide segmented Control

Tags: ios, swift, uisegmentedcontrol, uialertcontroller

I have two buttons, one that shows the segmented control and one that tries to hide it. The problem is when I click the one to show it, it works. However, when I click the one to hide it, it doesn't work. Here is my code:

```
let delayHide = UIAlertAction(title: "Hide Delay", style: .default) { (action) in
    self.segmentedHidden = 1
    self.setupSegmented()
}

let delayShow = UIAlertAction(title: "Show Delay", style: .default) { (action) in
    self.segmentedHidden = 0
    self.setupSegmented()
}
```

Here is also the code for when I try to hide it:

```
if (segmentedHidden == 0) {
    segmentedControl.isHidden = false
} else {
    segmentedControl.isHidden = true
}
```

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: your current code seems fine, please share more code to figure out the issue. make sure you are hiding and showing same instance of segmentedControl.

Answer (score 0):

Use following code:

```
    @IBAction func buttonTapped(_ sender: UIButton) {

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Segment", preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Show", style: .default, handler: { (alertAction) in
            self.showHideSegmentControl(isHidden: false)
        }))
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "hide", style: .default, handler: { (alertAction) in
            self.showHideSegmentControl(isHidden: true)
        }))
        self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }

    func showHideSegmentControl(isHidden: Bool) {
        segmentedControl.isHidden = isHidden
    }
```

Comment: Problem is that I have created my segmentedControl in another function so i can't call self.segmentedcontrol...

Comment: You can call that function in place of "self.segmentedControl.isHidden = false / true"

Comment: still says that my viewcontroller has no member segmentedcontroller

Comment: I created my segmentedControl in the viewDidLoad, was I not supposed to?

Comment: That's the issue, you have to declare outside of viewDidLoad() as follows and bind it with UISegmentedControl in Storyboard.
@IBOutlet weak var segmentedControl: UISegmentedControl!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187099/discussion-between-bhavik-modi-and-marco-cappai).